# SQL Server 2016 extract info from XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2016

I've been through various posts on the same subject but I can't seem to be able to get to the data elements in my XML file.

Here is a snippet of my XML :

```
   <ed:Certificate xmlns="http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-multiple-submission-schema.xsd" xmlns:ed="http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-submission-schema.xsd"> <ed:Status Code="39">Approved</ed:Status>   <ed:LastUpdatedDate>2021-03-10T14:20:55+13:00</ed:LastUpdatedDate>   <ed:Identifiers>
        <ed:CertificateID>NZL2021/MEABC/26913T</ed:CertificateID>
        <ed:TemplateID>ED1.6</ed:TemplateID>   </ed:Identifiers>   <ed:Exhausted>true</ed:Exhausted>   <ed:AutoApproval>false</ed:AutoApproval>   <ed:DepartureDate>2021-03-10</ed:DepartureDate>   <ed:Parties>
        <ed:ConsignorID>MEABC</ed:ConsignorID>
        <ed:ConsigneeID>FLIGHT1</ed:ConsigneeID>   </ed:Parties>   <ed:Transport>
        <ed:Ports>
          <ed:LoadingPortID>NZTRG</ed:LoadingPortID>
        </ed:Ports>
        <ed:FinalDestination>OAKLAND, United States</ed:FinalDestination>
        <ed:TransportMode>1</ed:TransportMode>
        <ed:LocalCarrier>MDH2</ed:LocalCarrier>
        <ed:CarrierName> Ever Given</ed:CarrierName>
        <ed:ConveyanceReference>V1234</ed:ConveyanceReference>   </ed:Transport>   <ed:Remarks>
        <ed:Remark>
          <ed:RemarkType>Unofficial Information</ed:RemarkType>
          <ed:RemarkValue>Vessel ETD - 19/03/21\nTARE WEIGHT - 2880 KGS</ed:RemarkValue>
        </ed:Remark>   </ed:Remarks>   <ed:Products>
        <ed:Product>
          <ed:ProductItem>1</ed:ProductItem>
          <ed:Exhausted>true</ed:Exhausted>
          <ed:Origin>AO</ed:Origin>
          <ed:Description>BONELESS BEEF RUMP CAP</ed:Description>
          <ed:CommonName>Bovine</ed:CommonName>
          <ed:EligibilityCountries>
            <ed:EligibilityCountryID>US</ed:EligibilityCountryID>
          </ed:EligibilityCountries>
          <ed:IntendedUse>consumption</ed:IntendedUse>
          <ed:GrossWeight unitCode="KGM">296.4</ed:GrossWeight>
          <ed:NetWeight unitCode="KGM">271.6</ed:NetWeight>
          <ed:Remarks>
            <ed:Remark>
              <ed:RemarkType>Product Statement</ed:RemarkType>
              <ed:RemarkValue>Item No. 81625\nLabel Approval 2659305 &amp; 91060858</ed:RemarkValue>
            </ed:Remark>
          </ed:Remarks>
          <ed:Classifications>
            <ed:Classification>
              <ed:ClassificationType>Temperature</ed:ClassificationType>
              <ed:ClassificationValue>chilled</ed:ClassificationValue>
            </ed:Classification>
            <ed:Classification>
              <ed:ClassificationType>New Zealand Harmonised System Code</ed:ClassificationType>
              <ed:ClassificationValue>020130</ed:ClassificationValue>
            </ed:Classification>
            <ed:Classification>
              <ed:ClassificationType>Halal Product</ed:ClassificationType>
              <ed:ClassificationValue>1</ed:ClassificationValue>
            </ed:Classification>
          </ed:Classifications>
          <ed:Containers>
            <ed:Container>
              <ed:ID>CGMU3099999</ed:ID>
              <ed:Seals>
                <ed:ID>NZMPIXXXXX</ed:ID>
              </ed:Seals>
            </ed:Container>
          </ed:Containers>
          <ed:Packaging>
            <ed:Package>
              <ed:Quantity>29</ed:Quantity>
              <ed:Type>CT</ed:Type>
              <ed:Level>1</ed:Level>
              <ed:ShippingMarks>
                <ed:Name>MABC\n26913</ed:Name>
              </ed:ShippingMarks>
            </ed:Package>
          </ed:Packaging>
          <ed:Processes>
            <ed:Process>
              <ed:ProcessTypeCode>SLT</ed:ProcessTypeCode>
              <ed:StartDate>2021-03-01</ed:StartDate>
              <ed:EndDate>2021-03-01</ed:EndDate>
              <ed:DateOverride>false</ed:DateOverride>
              <ed:Premise>
                <ed:ID>MEABC</ed:ID>
              </ed:Premise>
            </ed:Process>
            <ed:Process>
              <ed:ProcessTypeCode>PRO</ed:ProcessTypeCode>
              <ed:StartDate>2021-03-02</ed:StartDate>
              <ed:EndDate>2021-03-02</ed:EndDate>
              <ed:DateOverride>false</ed:DateOverride>
              <ed:Premise>
                <ed:ID>MEABC</ed:ID>
              </ed:Premise>
            </ed:Process>
            <ed:Process>
              <ed:ProcessTypeCode>CST</ed:ProcessTypeCode>
              <ed:StartDate>2021-03-02</ed:StartDate>
              <ed:EndDate>2021-03-10</ed:EndDate>
              <ed:DateOverride>false</ed:DateOverride>
              <ed:Premise>
                <ed:ID>MEABC</ed:ID>
              </ed:Premise>
            </ed:Process>
          </ed:Processes>
        </ed:Product> 
</ed:Products>  
     </ed:Certificate>
```

This is what I have tried so far  - Figured if I can access one element, I can slowly work on the rest

```
  if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XmlImportTest') is not null
    drop table #XmlImportTest
      
    CREATE TABLE #XmlImportTest(
    xmlFileName VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    xml_data XML NOT NULL
    );
    
    DECLARE @xmlFileName VARCHAR(200) ='K:\Upload\CSNXML\WaybillXml.xml'
    EXEC('INSERT INTO #XmlImportTest(xmlFileName, xml_data)
    
    SELECT ''' + @xmlFileName + ''', xmlData
    FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @xmlFileName + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA
    ) AS FileImport (XMLDATA)
    ')
    
    DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
    
    SELECT @xml = (SELECT xml_data from #XmlImportTest)
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
        
        DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
        
        SELECT @xml = (SELECT xml_data from #XmlImportTest)
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-multiple-submission-schema.xsd' AS ed)
    
    SELECT 
    
    p.value(N'@ProductItem',N'nvarchar(10)') AS ProductItem
          
    FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/Certificate')
      
    AS A(p)
    CROSS APPLY a.p.nodes(N'Products/Product') AS B(m);
```

I don't get any results returned.

I get the same result using OPENROWSET as well.

Can someone please tell me how I can access this data element.

Comment: `sp_xml_preparedocument ` is unnecessary with the newer `.nodes` and `.value` functions. What nodes/elements are you trying to get?

Comment: @charlieface i need to read this xml and create a report for end user consumption. I use ssrs for reporting. I need to be able to read pretty much every node .. but if you can get me started on getting all the product details that would be fantastic.  I.e. shipping marks, container, what products are included, weight etc.

Comment: Is the example XML "real data"? Seems to be missing the closing `</ed:Products>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be getting confused about XML Namespaces. The example document defines two namespace URIs:

1. http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-multiple-submission-schema.xsd, which has no prefix so is considered to be the "default" namespace of the document.
2. http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-submission-schema.xsd, which uses the `ed` namespace prefix that, by eyeballing it, seems to be used on every element in the document so might as well be the default namespace.

Your simplest example is trying to extract the value of the `/Certificate/Products/Product/ProductItem` elements which could be done as simply as:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  default 'http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-submission-schema.xsd'
)
select productItem.value(N'text()[1]', N'int') as ProductItem
from @xml.nodes('/Certificate/Products/Product/ProductItem') as p(productItem);
```

Expanding on this to select a few more values, you can see the `@` being used here to access the `unitCode` attribute of an element:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  default 'http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-submission-schema.xsd'
)
select
  product.value(N'(ProductItem/text())[1]', N'int') as ProductItem,
  product.value(N'(Exhausted/text())[1]', N'bit') as Exhausted,
  product.value(N'(Origin/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(2)') as Origin,
  product.value(N'(GrossWeight/text())[1]', N'decimal(19,1)') as GrossWeight,
  product.value(N'(GrossWeight/@unitCode)[1]', N'nvarchar(3)') as GrossWeightUnitCode
from @xml.nodes('/Certificate/Products/Product') as p(product);
```

It should be clear from the above two queries that the namespace prefixes used XPath query don't have to be the same as the ones used in the XML document - it's the namespace URIs themselves that matter. The prefixes in the document are used to link the elements (and sometimes attributes) to their namespace URIs, the prefixes used in XPath can be completely different so long as they reference the correct namespace URIs. e.g. this query returns the same result as the second example above, despite their being no `submission` prefixes in the source XML:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  'http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-multiple-submission-schema.xsd' as multiple,
  'http://sancrt.mpi.govt.nz/ecert/2013/ed-submission-schema.xsd' as submission
)
select
  product.value(N'(submission:ProductItem/text())[1]', N'int') as ProductItem,
  product.value(N'(submission:Exhausted/text())[1]', N'bit') as Exhausted,
  product.value(N'(submission:Origin/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(2)') as Origin,
  product.value(N'(submission:GrossWeight/text())[1]', N'decimal(19,1)') as GrossWeight,
  product.value(N'(submission:GrossWeight/@unitCode)[1]', N'nvarchar(3)') as GrossWeightUnitCode,
product.value(N'(submission:Remarks/submission:Remark/submission:RemarkType/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as item_remark
from @xml.nodes('/submission:Certificate/submission:Products/submission:Product') as p(product);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I can get to the RemarkValue in the Products node please? I Tried this but get NULL -> product.value(N'(submission:Remarks/Remark/RemarkType/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as item_remark

Comment: You're very close. Remember that the `Remarks`, `Remark` and `RemarkType` elements in the XML document are all declared to be in the same namespace, so you need to use the same prefix for each of them in the XPath query.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. this worked :  product.value(N'(submission:Remarks/submission:Remark/submission:RemarkType/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') as item_remark